# How to filter correctly in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the filter function in Excel to display only relevant things.  But when I filter certain dates, I lose my blanks. Can someone please show me a trick around this?

[image]

Here are a couple pictures that show what my issue is.
In the first picture, say I have apples, strawberries, and turnips. But I only want to see feb 15,16,& 17. So when I apply filter, I get whats in the second picture, which is just apples. I still want to see strawberries and turnips.

[image]

Comment: You need to fill in the blanks with the date.  Excel is looking for like data and reads the cells as blanks and not the date that is above.

Comment: I've done that before and it works, but it's time consuming...is there any quicker way?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in a worksheet with autofilter enabled or in an Excel Table object (created with Insert > Table), then the filters will ony show the data that have the actual filter value, not the blanks. You need to fill the blanks to contain the date.

The fastest way to do that is to

- select the date column
- hit F5
- click the Special button
- tick Blanks and click OK
- type a = sign in the active cell
- hit the up arrow
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter
- select column A again and copy
- use Paste Special to paste values only

Now there are no blanks in column A, but real dates, and the filter will work on all rows.

Another option to filter by date is to create a pivot table from the original data. Again, each row of the original data would need a date, no blanks allowed. Then you can build a pivot table and group by date. Pivot tables can be formatted to show the data like your first screenshot, but all data will be included if the data is filtered.

[image]